# actionPerformed method call Java

Tags: java, interface, nullpointerexception, awt

I built an interface and when I call the actionPerformed method it gives me errors.

**My method:**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento){
    Button active;
    active = (Button) evento.getSource(); //line 144
    if(active==botonSalir) 
        mainF.dispose();
    ...
}
```

**The main method:**

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    InterfaceE objetoM = new InterfaceE();
    objetoM.actionPerformed(); //line 195
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at InterfaceE.actionPerformed(InterfazceE.java:144)
    at InterfaceE.main(InterfaceE.java:195)
```

What should be the parameters in `InterfaceE()`?

Comment: how looks body of actionPerformed() method?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  If posting code snippets, indicate which line is line 144.

Comment: Also, if that's how the actionPerformed method was defined, your code wouldn't even compile, since it takes an ActionEven as parameter, and you call it without any argument.

Comment: Is InterfaceE is of type interface? How compiler allowing you to compile it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you must be invoking method of `Interfaz` when Interfaz object is not assigned or it must be null inside `actionPerformed()` method. `objectM` is not `null` which is sure as I can see the code. But you have not pasted code for `actionPerformed()` method. Let's see the code in `actionPerformed()` method so that we can give you exact answer.

**Update** after your edit in question.

aren't you getting `compile time` error as you have called no argument `acionPerformed` method ? `actionPerformed` must be taking `anonymous`  object of `ActionEvent` class with `getSource()` method implemented. You are not sending `ActionEvent` anonymous object in `actionPerformed` method as a argument. 
Is your code at line no. 195 looking like,

```
objetoM.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(){ //this is your line 195 for anonymous object.
     public ReturnType getSource(){
           // some code
     }
}
);
```

Comment: As pointed out by @JBNizet, the code used ***must*** be different to that shown in the snippets above.  Post an SSCCE.

Comment: what else should my code include? I posted the most relevant of each method and posted the whole main method :(

Comment: now you have edited Interfaz to InterfazceE. Would you help us to paste some relevant code snippet? I know after sometime you (yourself) will get rid  of this NullPointerExceptioin :-)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I had given possible answer in the very first line, so is an answer not a comment :-)

Comment: InterfaceE is the name of the class and the builder method only initializes all the graphic elements. The posted above is the relevant portion of the code, isn't it?